# How to solve multiple times api key error on same page

Tags: javascript, php

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQcJL.png I have added one api for wp job manager and one api for wp google map pro plugin. If i use single plugin its functionality is working correctly. If I use both plugin it is not working properly api is conflicting.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any of your code I'm going to guess you are including two script tags for google maps. If you combine these into a single tag it should solve your problem.

```
<!-- Two separate script tags -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>

<!-- Single script tag -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```